# Negating a regular expression in Javascript in situations not covered in earlier posts

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Before you mark this as duplicate, let me assure you that I have gone through, hopefully, all of the questions asked on the subject on stackoverflow, including the following:

[How can I invert a regular expression in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538512/how-can-i-invert-a-regular-expression-in-javascript)

[negation in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680098/negation-in-regular-expression)

I am trying to parse a string with syntax as follows:

```
 contents = "Some Random Text1 <@@Matched text 1@@> Some Random Text2 <@@Matched text 2@@> Some Random Text3";
```

I used the regular express:

```
 reg_exp = /\<\!\!.*?\!\!\>/g
```

and then used the following code to extract the Matched Text and make a long string out of it with a blank delimiter in between each match.

```
 while ((matched_array = reg_exp.exec(contents)) != null) {
     matched_text +=  (matched_array[0] + "");
 };
```

This returns matched_text as:

```
  <@@Matched text 1@@> <@@Matched text 2@@>
```

All this works fine.
Now I want to get a substring of all text outside the matched text.

I cannot set a regular expression to do the same with the text outside the matched text, to generate the following result string for the above example:

```
  Some Random Text1 Some Random Text2 Some Random Text3
```

I tried all possible solutions provided in the above cited posts, including (?! or ^ after grouping (), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `string.replace` function to replace those matched chars with an empty string.

```js
var string =  "Some Random Text1 <@@Matched text 1@@> Some Random Text2 <@@Matched text 2@@> Some Random Text3";
alert(string.replace(/\s*<@@.*?@@>/g, ''))
```

Comment: Certainly this should do the job but I just want to wait and see if there is a way to negate the regular expression used which can also do the job. If no other answer along this line comes along, I will accept your answer. Actually, your answer is  easy to understand and very logical too.

Comment: generally, when needed, you should use many RegExps instead one giant monstrosity for both performance and readability.

Comment: @dandavis, Can you suggest how one can handle my problem with multipe regex?